# KVO keyPath for "self"

Tags: ios, objective-c, nssortdescriptor

I'm trying to create a sortDescriptor for an `NSArray` of `NSStrings`.

I'm just not sure what to put for the `key` parameter as I want to use "self" or something equivalent as I just want to use the standard `NSString` `compare`.

In this code...

```
[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"..." ascending:YES];
```

What should I put where the ... is? `self`?

Comment: I don't understand how do you want to use `self` as property key? And why do you need `self`, if you compare strings?

Comment: How else would you use `[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:ascending:];` to sort an `NSArray` of `NSStrings`? I don't WANT to use `self` I just want the key path that refers to the actual `NSString` not a property of it. Or would you use something entirely different to sort the `NSArray`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self` should work. You could also use `description`, in that case the sort would not just work for NSString but also for NSNumber.

Comment: `self` works for NSNumber as well, there is no need to use `description`.

Comment: @MartinR do you just use "self" then? I wasn't sure if it should be blank or "self" or "." or something else?

Comment: @Fogmeister: Yes, a plain `self`. (`self` is a method of `NSObject` and returns ... "self" :-) Alternatively, you can sort the array with `[array sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)]`.